# Chrome extension content script keeps getting executed on every other tab reload not just on newly opened tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm having a case where I'm unable to figure out what's happening. I've created a chrome extension that overrides the blank new tab's content. All working fine, but I got a couple of errors on other already open tabs whenever refreshing. The extension get's executed even in existing windows, causing me troubles. I've been trying to find some info on the lifecycle of an extension using `chrome_url_overrides: newtab` to learn about its behavior, but couldn't find anything.

[Updating to include the full sample, also [here's](https://file.io/YC0gtoSohUNQ) a minimum example reproducing the issue - per your request]

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Homepage",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "identity"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["index.js"],
      "type": "module"
    }
  ]
}
```

script.js (that's all in there)

```
console.log('Hello from Chrome Homepage');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <home-page></home-page>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can think of a couple of options to prevent the extension from being executed outside of the new tab opens, but would first try to understand why my extension keeps being executed also in current tabs, instead of just when opening a blank one.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without seeing manifest.json I guess you have `content_scripts` there, so just remove it, you don't need it.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! In the meantime I've updated the question by adding everything (manifest included). So there's no need to declare `script.js` as content script in this case?

Comment: No. Content scripts are for web pages, see the documentation for more info.